# A program run as console but not as Windows service

Tags: .net, windows, service

We are running some of the components of our application as scheduled windows services.  The basic operation is, check a database and based on a flag a call to login service of a different application is called using httpclient.  We are using c# as coding language.

The same code when run as a console application is executing fine but when run as windows service is not giving response after call to other
application URL.

Could any one tell me probable cause of this behavior?

Comment: Do you write logs in order to be sure that the execution reach the call?

Comment: When we debug the code, we observed code which calls external URL is hit but no response on that line .  Execution never moves to next line.  We are not writing logs.

Comment: Do you have any mean to check if the call is received on the other side, the login service application?

Comment: yes we checked with other application and got to know that it is not reaching that application

Comment: These failures are usually caused by [running in the system account](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#AppNotWorkingFromService). Try running your service in a regular login account and see if the problem persists.